# Meteor- unable to show popup widget for elements in a list

Tags: jquery, meteor, popup, semantic-ui

Hello I am using Meteor + Semantic UI but I think this applies to other JQuery-based widgets (Bootstrap).  I want to show a popup for each item in a list.  The problem is with initialization I think.

```
<!-- entity.html -->
<template name="listEntities">
<div class="ui list">
    {{#each entities}}
        <div class="item">
            <p>
                {{> entityItem}}
            </p>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
</template>

<template name="entityItem">
<div class="small blue ui labeled icon buttons">
    <div class="ui button my-btn-entity">
        <i class="doc basic icon"></i>
        {{name}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="small blue ui icon buttons">
    <div class="circular ui button my-btn-entity-info" data-content="{{description}}">
        <i class="info icon"></i>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
</template>


//entity-client.js
Template.listEntities.helpers({
    entities: function(){
        return Entities.find().fetch();
    }
});

Template.listEntities.rendered = function(){
    //initialize popup
    $('.my-btn-entity-info').popup();
};

Template.listEntities.events({
    'click .my-btn-entity-info': function(event){
        event.currentTarget.popup({ //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            title: this.name,
            content: this.description,
            on: 'click'
        });
    }
});
```

When I click on the info button (class=my-btn-entity-info), I get this error

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function entity-client.js:75

Template.listEntities.events.click .my-btn-entity-info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` returns a DOM element, whilst Semantic-UI attaches `popup` (and so on) to the jQuery wrapper around DOM elements.

So you need to do:

```
$(event.currentTarget).popup({
    title: this.name,
    content: this.description,
    on: 'click'
});
```

or even better:

```
'click .my-btn-entity-info': function(event, template){
    template.$(event.currentTarget).popup({
        title: this.name,
        content: this.description,
        on: 'click'
    });
}
```

That guarantees you don't accidentally pick up anything outside of the template in question, and should make things run marginally (although imperceptibly) faster as it won't have to traverse the entire document.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick reply.  I tried each of your methods and the error now goes away.  However no popup.  I tried with static title and content but still nothing.  When I click the button I see in the console: Popup: 4ms semantic.min.js:12
div.circular.ui.button.my-btn-entity-info  “Initializing module"
div.circular.ui.button.my-btn-entity-info  "Storing instance of module"

Comment: I removed all initialization code and get the same behavior.  So I think the problem is I am no initializing the elements in the list.  Documentation suggests I need to call element.popup() on render of each element in the list.  http://semantic-ui.com/module.html#/init  Tried numerous ways.  How to do that?

Comment: nooitaf:semantic-ui  I see in my .meteor/versions file that it says I have this version:  nooitaf:semantic-ui@0.0.1  I ran 'meteor update nooitaf:semantic-ui' but it still says 0.0.1

Comment: I believe there is a bug in nooitaf:semantic-ui that prevented my popovers to work for me.  Please see my post below on how to get popups/popovers to work in Bootstrap as a workaround.  I am marking your answer as the answer because you did resolve my first problem.  Thanks!

Comment: do `meteor update --packages-only` or just `meteor update`, the latest version of `nooitaf:semantic-ui` is `0.19.3` not `0.0.1`

Comment: @richsilv i've been working with meteor and semantic-ui for a few months now and could really never get a handle on how to handle on how to properly wrap the functions. this was very helpful haha

Comment: Are there any instances where semantic-ui elements would need to be initialized in on OnCreated function? I have a nav bar like this, but it's a little buggy. would you mind looking at at here: http://jsfiddle.net/fq22fdfv/ would really appreciate it ! @richsilv

Answer (score -1):

OK I tried many things.
This is the workaround that worked for me, bypassing what I believe to be a bug in nooitaf:semantic-ui package for Meteor.  I posted this bug here
https://github.com/nooitaf/meteor-semantic-ui/issues/22

My fix is a workaround - I switched to bootstrap, and used popovers.  They worked instantly.  I have to say that with Bootstrap instead of Semantic-UI, my buttons look better.  My opinion.

```
meteor remove nooitaf:semantic-ui
meteor add meteor add nemo64:bootstrap less
```

See https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap for initializing the Bootstrap modules.  I had to create file custom.bootstrap.json and switch these to true:

```
"buttons":              true,
"glyphicons":           true,
"button-groups":        true,
"popovers":             true,
```

Next I modified my template:

```
<!-- entity.html -->
<template name="listEntities">
<div class="list">
    {{#each entities}}
    <div class="item">
        <p>
            {{> entityItem}}
        </p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
</template>

<template name="entityItem">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> {{name}}
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="my-btn-entity-info-{{_id}}" class="btn btn-primary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" title="{{name}}" data-content="{{description}}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </button>
</div>
</template>
```

Finally I used the latest version of initialization that had failed with semantic-ui, and it now works.

```
//entity-client.js
Template.entityItem.rendered = function() {
    var infoItemSelector = "#my-btn-entity-info-" + this.data._id;
    console.log(infoItemSelector);
    $(infoItemSelector).popover();
};
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I have my packages `richsilv:semantic-ui` and `richsilv:semantic-ui-sass` working fine with popups by just adding a `data-content` attribute and then calling `$('data-content').popup()` in the rendered callback.